# registerEventTimeTimer is not firing with watermark

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using KafkaSource to read kafka messages of Events type, as per documentation providing event time extractor is optional for source kafka

```
  KafkaSource<Events> source =
                KafkaSource.<Events>builder()
                        .setProperties(kafkaProperties)
                        .setBootstrapServers(parameters.get("bootstrap-servers-source"))
                        .setTopics(parameters.get("source-topic"))
                        .setGroupId("visit-events-flink-mvp")
                        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets(OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST))
                        //.setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                        .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new EventsDeserializationSchema())
                        .build();

        // event stream from kafka source
        DataStream<Events> eventStream =
                env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps(), "Kafka Source")
                        //should be a unique id
                        .uid("kafka-source");

        //stream is keyed based on the anonymousId
        DataStream<Events> keyedStream =
                eventStream.keyBy(Events::getAnonymousId)
                        //  .process(new KeyedProcessing(Long.parseLong(parameters.get("ttl"))))
                        .process(new KeyedProcessingWithCallBack(Long.parseLong(parameters.get("ttl"))))
                        .uid("engager-events-keyed-processing");
```

In my KeyedProcessingWithCallBack, I'm setting  event time timer for 60 secs and the call back is not triggering at all.

**My kafka source has 8 partitions and I'm running job with parallelism 1**

```
 public void processElement(EngagerEvents value, KeyedProcessFunction<String, EngagerEvents, String>.Context ctx, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(value.getEventString());
        System.out.println("time : " +jsonNode.get("EVENT_TIMESTAMP").textValue());
        if (anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.value() == null) {
            System.out.println("time stamp emitting: " +jsonNode.get("EVENT_TIMESTAMP").textValue());
            // key is not available in the state
            anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.update(true);
            System.out.println("TIMER START TIME: " +ctx.timestamp());
            out.collect(value.getEventString());
            ctx.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(ctx.timestamp() + (stateTtl * 1000));
        }
    }

    

    // not getting triggered
    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<String> out)
            throws Exception {
        // triggers after ttl has passed
        System.out.println("Call back triggered : time : " +timestamp + " value : " +anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.value());
       anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.clear();
    }
```

**TEST Simulator code which will send event with anonymousId=111 with different event time stamp**

```
try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                String[] anonymousId = {"111"};
                String key = String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(10));
                ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(
                        "flink-visits-mvp-test-source",
                        key,
                        //   getEvent(UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "-"  +Thread.currentThread().getName() , event[new Random().nextInt(1)]));
                        // getEvent(anonymousId[new Random().nextInt(1)], event[new Random().nextInt(1)]));
                        getEvent(anonymousId[new Random().nextInt(1)],
                                System.currentTimeMillis(),
                                event));

                //System.out.println(record.value().toString());
                    producer.send(record);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Am I doing something wrong here ? Why is my event time timer call back not trgiggering ?**

Comment: Why don't you directly map to your Object type? Why do you need to deserialize it as a string and then map it to an object?

Comment: thanks for your response, I have added deserialization schema now to convert string to required type. However my event time timer which is set to 60 secs is not firing. Can you point out what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Hi @SuchethShivakumar were you able to solve the issue? I am facing the same issue. Appreciate if you can share how you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I also experience the same error with Flink V1.16. The processElement method is invoked as expected however, observed that **ctx.timerService().currentWatermark()** always print as -9223372036854775808. onTimer method never invoked with 60 seconds timer.

With lots of trial and error I found that invoking env.setParallelism() method resolve the issue.

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setParallelism(1);
```

After fix, the currentWatermark() method return correct watermark time and onTimer method is invoked every 60 seconds.

Here is the log entries before fix:

> Event Time = 1669610765000, End Of Window Time = 1669610819999,
> current water mark time = -9223372036854775808
>
> Event Time = 1669610807000, End Of Window Time = 1669610819999,
> current water mark time = -9223372036854775808

Here is the log entries after fix:

> Event Time = 1669610393000, End Of Window Time = 1669610399999,
> current water mark time = 1669610387999
>
> Event Time = 1669610450000, End Of Window Time = 1669610459999,
> current water mark time = 1669610435999